# Change Packets in Android

Tags: android, network-programming, vpn, packet-capture

I want to implement an android app that can control and change packets on network communications.

For ex: A parental control app.

some web sites should be restricted by app and a predefined page should appear in browser instead of original page.

One solution I have already read about is `vpn` connection. But as far as I know this solution need a server that can handle packets. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality without `vpn` using an alternative method. Any hint in the direction of suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the approach would not be to change packets but perform a decisive action on receiving packets from a particular IP address.

For example, in designing a parental control app, you would like to restrict the user to open www.facebook.com
One way of doing it is building a sniffer which would first receive the packet and then transfer the packet to the network connection. On receiving the packet you could code a filter for such websites and hence control traffic.